# Download xml file on android from server with basic authentication

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to download an xml file a server that requires basic authentication on android. Someone please help as i need to get this done today. I have tried multiple ways but none of them works.

I have tried the async method from this tutorial here [Download a file with Android, and showing the progress in a ProgressDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog)

it gives me a 404 error and am sure the url works fine because me chrome browser can download the xml file fine

Comment: I like using okhttp for android. Here are some links to get you started: http://square.github.io/okhttp/  use Credentials class to set your basic auth headers http://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/Credentials.html

Comment: Thanks for your response but can post an example code please. I have looked at it but i don't think it works

Comment: Why don't you post what you've tried so far that isn't working and we can see what your problem is. OkHttp has some recipes (code examples) here https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes

Comment: I have edited it to show what i have tried